# URL Masking not working with https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-masking

I have a website that's being targeted by spammers and I want to show them a different version of the site (with no forms) when they come visit our pages. I need to keep the same URLs in the Browser Bar but show them a similar page in a Folder.

For example: `example.com/contactform.html` would keep the url but would show them: `example.com/decoy/contactform.html`

The whole site would be duplicated inside folder DECOY but mainly with all forms in the pages removed.

I was able to make it work with a test site but when I tried to do it with my site (which it's https), it didn't work as the URL in the browser Bar changes (i.e. it shows: `example.com/decoy/contactform.html`)

Maybe things are different with https? Can you you help?  Thanks! Here it's my code:

```
# INI suspicious IP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^23\.26\.131\.  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^24\.121\.216\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/decoy/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
# END suspicious IP
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to go the PHP way of pulling the other page at every page. For example: target_page.html
`<?php
$deny = array("111.111.111", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
 $crawl = 'https://www.example.com/decoy/target_page.html';
 $fd = fopen($crawl, "r");
 while($buf = fgets($fd,1024))
 {
 echo $buf;
 }
 fclose($fd);
} else {

...

}?>`

Comment: Nobody seems to know ?